# Javascript generating a dynamic json response

Tags: javascript, json, string, parsing

Im trying to create a dynamic JSON object based on specific data. [Source code](https://gist.github.com/3282454)

If I enter the following text:

```
here
is
an:example
of:
how:this:works
```

It generates:

```
[
  "here",
  "is",
  {
    "an": "example"
  },
  {
    "of": ""
  },
  {
    "how": {
      "this": "works"
    }
  }
]
```

How can I get it to return the following: (because of foo having no value, pushing the objects into an array)

```
[
  "here",
  "is",
  {
    "an": "example"
  },
  {
    "of": [
      "how": {
        "this": "works"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not quite clear, so I have to guess... Do you want to put all the values that follow `of:` into an array? So basically one could write the original input with indents as follows (with every indent signifying a new array)?

```
here
is
an:example
of:
    how:this:works:
        foo:bar
        example
```

Besides, your second JSON example is not correct, the content of the `of:` array would have to be wrapped in braces since arrays can't have keys.

Well, assuming you wanted to have the result I described above, you could quite easily do this with recursion:

```
var jsonify = function(input) {
    var helper = function(items) {
        var end = [];
        for (i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
            var itemparts = items[i].split(':');
            var value = itemparts.pop();
            var dobreak = false;
            while (itemparts.length) {
                var obj = {};
                if (value == "" && i+1 < items.length) {
                    // Recursive call
                    value = helper(items.slice(i+1,items.length));
                    dobreak = true;
                }
                obj[itemparts.pop()] = value;
                value = obj;
            }
            end.push(value);
            if (dobreak) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return end;
    };

    return helper(input.split('\r\n'));
};
```

This function searches for zero length values and checks if there are values in the following lines. If so, all the values that follow (`items.slice(...)`) are processed separately with the same function (i.e. recursively) to put them into an array.

When calling `jsonify` with the example input above, you'll get the following JSON:

```
[
    "here",
    "is",
    {
        "an": "example"
    },
    {
        "of": [
            {
                "how": {
                    "this": {
                        "works": [
                            {
                                "foo": "bar"
                            },
                            "example"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Hope that helps... ;)